# How to attach the screenshot to each step in ExtentReport?

Tags: cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I'm trying to use ExtentReport with Cucumber v4. I'm able to generate the execution report at the end of the test case, including the proper step list (for all steps that were executed) with their screenshots.

However, although the screenshots are properly generated, the link that ties the step with its respective screenshot seems to be broken (when clicking on it, nothing happens).

Any ideas of what should I try?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Report]